# How to prove $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^k}$ is a Cauchy Sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I know that for a sequence to be a Cauchy sequence $\forall\epsilon > 0$ , $\exists M \in \mathbb R$ such that if  $n,m > M$ then $|a_{n} - a_{m}| < \epsilon$

To start I have been told that $M = \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ however I am not sure how to proceed from here. I am mostly confused on the *structure* of the Cauchy sequence proofs. Do I proceed to manipulate the expression $|a_{n} - a_{m}|$ like this? 
$$\left\lvert\frac{1}{2^m} -  \frac{1}{2^n}\right\rvert$$
If so, where do I go from here? Thank you.

Comment: I would start by assuming without loss of generality that $m \geq n$ so that $ m = n +k$ for some natural number $k$.

Comment: $|2^{-m}-2^{-n}|\leq 2^{-n+1}$ if $m\geq n$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove the geometric sequence $(r^n)$ is Cauchy if $|r|&lt;1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2998995/prove-the-geometric-sequence-rn-is-cauchy-if-r1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2^k}$.  Then, we have for $n>m$

$$\begin{align}|a_n-a_m|&=\left|\sum_{k=m+1}^n\frac1{2^k}\right|\\\\
&=\frac1{2^m}-\frac1{2^n}\\\\
&=\frac1{2^m}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n-m}}\right)\\\\&\le \frac1{2^m}\\\\
&<\varepsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $n>m>\frac{\log(1/\varepsilon)}{\log(2)}$

Comment: I don't follow the last sentence. How does that guarantee that $\frac{1}{2^m} < \epsilon$ ?

Comment: If $\frac1{2^m}<\varepsilon$, then $2^m>\frac1{\varepsilon}$ and $\log(2^m)>\log(1/\varepsilon)$ so that $$m>\frac{\log(1/\varepsilon)}{\log(2)}$$